# Python, result from Console,Error, String format

Tags: python, string, console

I have a problem with my console program.
A total of four initial results are expected from me, the interesting thing is that two of them work correctly, the other two make the following mistake...

Also, since I'm a beginner, I want to ask how to create a variable that can read both text and number.

[image]

Comment: Can you copy-paste the error in a code snippet please ? It will be good for accessibility (blind or partialy blind users). Also, provide a [mcve], that would be great !

Answer (score 0):

The best way to check if an input is an int is to try converting it to int, if it fails, then return it as a string.

```py
def input_text_or_int(msg):
    """
    Input text or integer
    """
    user_input = input(msg)
    try:
        return int(user_input)
    except ValueError:
        return user_input

input_text_or_int("Input text or integer: ")
```

Comment: Thank you! The best

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) If my answer helps you, feel free to upvote or accept it.